# How to cast objects with different classes in a Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

## Use Case

I'm using an 3rd party library where there are two very similar classes that don't implement an interface. The code currently loops through a list of items to find the first occurrence of an object using one of these classes and then converts it to a stream where it is processed. It would be nice if I could convert this code to use a stream and have it chained to the rest of my code.

### Current Code

```
    for (Component3Choice component: components) {
        if (component instanceof OptionalComponent3Bean) {
            OptionalComponent3Bean section = (OptionalComponent3Bean) component;

            entryStream = section.getSection().getEntry().stream()
            break;
        }
        else if (component instanceof RequiredComponent3Bean) {
            RequiredComponent3Bean section = (RequiredComponent3Bean) component;

            entryStream = section.getSection().getEntry().stream();
            break;
        }
    }
    ... do something with the stream ...
```

### Desired Code

```
components.stream()
  .filter(entry -> entry instanceof OptionalComponent3Bean 
                     || entry instanceof RequiredComponent3Bean)
  .findFirst()
  .map( {{ cast entry }} )
  .map( castedEntry.getSection().getEntry())
  ... continue on with my processing
```

### Question

Is it possible cast the entry based on the previous filter in the stream?

Comment: Does `Component3Choice` define a method `getSection()` ?

Comment: Can you modify `OptionalComponent3Bean` & `RequiredComponent3Bean` to implement an interface (for instance `HasSection`) which would define `getSection()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source code for that library. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing can save you from bad design, which is what it seems you're fighting against.

You can force a common interface by means of a wrapper, if you need to replicate boilerplate similar to this one in many places.
Otherwise, I guess the best you can do is

```
static private IDontKnow getStream(Component3Choice c3c) {
  if (c3c instanceof OptionalComponent3Bean) {
    return ((OptionalComponent3Bean)c3c).getStream();
  } else if (c3c instanceof RequiredComponent3Bean) {
    return ((RequiredComponent3Bean)c3c).getStream();
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

components.stream()
  .map(x -> getStream(x))
  .filter(x -> x!=null)
  .findFirst()
  .map(x -> x.getEntry().stream());
  ... continue on with yout processing
```

Comment: Looks good as this isolates the logic. if and when the library gets updated and hopefully fixed, it'll be easier to transition.

Comment: Chiming in re another case.  Wanting to stream members of a Set to .joining() but that looks for CharSequence instances like String, not Longs, etc..  This is what I did: setOfLongObjects.stream().map(it -> ""+it).collect(Collectors.joining(","))

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest code, but you could do :

```
components.stream()
          .filter(entry -> entry instanceof OptionalComponent3Bean 
                     || entry instanceof RequiredComponent3Bean)
          .map(entry -> {
                 if ((entry instanceof OptionalComponent3Bean)
                   return ((OptionalComponent3Bean) entry).getSection().getEntry().stream(); 
                 else
                   return ((RequiredComponent3Bean) entry).getSection().getEntry().stream();
                        })
          .findFirst();
```

This would return an `Optional<Stream<Something>>`.

Note that `findFirst` must be the last operation, since it's terminal.